# Failure during official firmware update - phone powered off and won't boot

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, rom

Phone: Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML

**Long story short**: I tried to install official firmware upgrade using `TWRP` > `Install` > `.zip`. The installation was going on for a couple of minutes and then the screen blacked out. Since then, the phone does not boot.

---

So, I got bored of my `Android 5` and decided to install a `custom ROM`, but I had to upgrade official firmware before that.

At first, I dove into `how to install custom ROM` tutorials, so I did the rooting first:

I downloaded a `BootLoaderUnlocker` program from the official Asus website and `unlocked the BL`. Then, I followed a tutorial for `one-click-root`, and succeded. Then I installed `TWRP` and flashed the `Recovery` to the latest available `img` for my phone and tried to install the `Lineage OS 14.1` but got `status 7` error, meaning something is incompatible.

[This post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone2/orig-development/rom-official-cyanogenmod-14-1-weekly-t3545692) states, that in order to install `Lineage OS 14.1` I have to have a firmware at least `MM 4.21.40.xx` which is `Android 6`, so I went to the official Asus website and downloaded the Firmware upgrade. Since, I probably had the wrong BL at that point, I flashed the bootloader with `TWRP for Z00A (Lollipop)    2.8.7.3` from [here](http://www.theflamingskull.com/zenfone2.html), which is the same website from which `the post` suggest to download a BL for MM (Android 6). I thought, since I currently have the Lolipop, should install the BL for that, just to be sure. Then I started the firmware upgrade, which rebooted the phone into the `BL`, I didn't think, and just pressed `Normal Boot` and the phone booted as usual in the old Android. Then I tried to initiate the instalation again but couldn't (it's supposed to auto-detect the file in the storage root), so I got an idea to just boot the `Recovery`, maybe it will continue. So, I did that, and the `TWRP` showed up (I forgot about it already and thought that the instalation would just continue), so I just pressed `Install` and chose the firmware upgrade `zip` manualy. The installation was going on for a couple of minutes and then the screen blacked out.

Since then, the phone does not boot. If I try to, it vibrates like it is going to boot, but then nothing happens (not even a logo).

I even tried to disconnect the battery: removed all the screws, removed the back panel and manually disconnected it. When I put it back the phone vibrated like it was going to boot, but nothing happened again.

P.S. I tried to boot into the `Recovery`, but that just does not work, and even did not work before the firmware upgrade (I googled, that I must press power and volume up and hold until the logo appears, but that doesn't happen).

upd: plugged into the charger, periodically shows the battery icon on the screen.

Comment: Plug the device into a computer and see if it is recognized

Comment: @EthanZ I used Soc USB driver: it is recognized for a second then it disappears. I think every time I try to boot, it vibrates and shuts down immediately.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then. It's probably hard bricked.

Comment: @EthanZ do you mean the hardware could be damaged during the installation?

Comment: typo at first i just fixed. Hard bricked, or only fixable by the manufacturer

Comment: @EthanZ I went to a service and the dude said I might have screwed up the `preLoader`, so some might say it's a disastah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went to a service and turns out I messed up the `PreLoader`, that boots the `BootLoader`. Sometimes this cannot be restored and costs a bunch of money to replace the memory block, but I got lucky and got the phone repaired.

P.S. Do not install official firmware with programs like `TWRP`, use only your manufacturer's software like, in my case, Asus flash-tool